# How to choose specific values in a csv file with python

Tags: python, csv, subtraction

I need to be able to do the subtraction between the bigger and smaller positive number in ColumnB that have ColumnA=1,ColumnC=0. (I wrote them between ** to make it clearer)
I have something like this in my csv file but I have a lot more rows.

> 

```
| Column A | Column B || Column C | Column D    |
| -------- | -------- || -------- | --------    |
| 1        |   -99    || 0        |    0.4567   |
| 1        |   -99    || 0        |     0.5678  |
| 1        | 60       || 40       |     0.123   |
| 1        | 67       || 60       |     0.2894  |
| 1        | **69**   || 0        |     0.3983  |
| 1        | 70       || 0        |     0.3983  |
| 1        | **71**   || 0        |     0.3983  | 
| 2        | -30      || 0        |     0.3983  | 
| 2        | -40      || 20       |     0.3983  | 
| 2        | 45       || 30       |     0.3983  | 
| 2        | 46       || 40       |     0.3983  |
```

I tried to create a new column like this but I don't have to do the mean I need to subtract the max with the min.

```
for u in range(1, 19):
        ColumnZ = df.query(f'ColumnB >0 & ColumnC == 0 & ColumnA == {u}')['ColumnB'].mean()
        test.loc[rowIndex, 'ColumnZ'] = ColumnZ
```

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you show your attempt and what issues you ran into making it work. SO isn't designed for people to write your code from scratch for you.

Comment: @Peter You're right! I added what I tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cat subtract.csv
Column A,Column B,Column C,Column D
1,-99,0,0.4567
1,67,60,0.2894
1,69,0,0.3983
1,71,0,0.3983

import csv

with open('subtract.csv', 'r', newline='') as csv_file:
    dReader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    number_list = []
    for row in dReader:
        if int(row['Column A']) == 1 and int(row['Column C']) == 0 and int(row['Column B']) >= 0:
            number_list.append(int(row['Column B']) )
    new_val = max(number_list) - min(number_list)
new_val

2
```